# How to find the particular value exist in json string

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here i have one array , in this array i have one more array called **studentabsentId** ,here actually studentabsentId 1 is absent on **2017-04-11** and **2017-04-12**

```
echo $json = json_encode($optionsList);
```

Result

```
 [
  {
    "studentabsentId": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-11"
  },
  {
    "studentabsentId": [
      "1"
    ],
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12"
  },
  {
    "studentabsentId": [
      "2"
    ],
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-13"
  }
]
```

studentabsentId 2 is absent 2017-04-11 and 2017-04-13,now what i want to do means id 2 is which are the date is absent,

Expected results

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "studentAbsentId":  "2"
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-11",
       "response":"absent"
    },

 {
  "studentAbsentId":  "2"
  "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-13",
  "response":"absent"
}
]
}
```

> My updated code

```
$json = json_encode($optionsList);
             $result = array();
                for($i = 0; $i<count($json); $i++){
                    for($j = 0; $j<count($json[$i]->studentabsentId); $j++){
                        if($json[$i]->studentabsentId[$j] === "2"){
                            array_push($result, 
                              (object)[
                                "studentabsentId" => $json[$i]->studentabsentId[$j], 
                                "studentAbsentDate" => $json[$i]->studentAbsentDate, 
                              ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //echo(print_r($result));

                $expected_result = (object)[
                  "status"  => "Success",
                  "data" => $result
                ];

                echo(print_r($expected_result));
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: Mr @  Jay Blanchard, i don't have idea how to do,so can you please update the answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a free crowd-sourced code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP version, sandbox `http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7991f23dc9bdd304eb50e27a06b68495564fa94`:

```
<?php
$json = array(
 (object) [
    "studentabsentId" => array("1", "2"),
    "studentAbsentDate" => "2017-04-11"
  ],
  (object) [
    "studentabsentId" => array("1"),
    "studentAbsentDate" => "2017-04-12"
  ],
  (object) [
    "studentabsentId" => array("2"),
    "studentAbsentDate" => "2017-04-13"
  ]
);
//echo(print_r($json));

$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i<count($json); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j<count($json[$i]->studentabsentId); $j++){
        if($json[$i]->studentabsentId[$j] === "2"){
            array_push($result, 
              (object)[
                "studentabsentId" => $json[$i]->studentabsentId[$j], 
                "studentAbsentDate" => $json[$i]->studentAbsentDate, 
              ]);
        }
    }
}
//echo(print_r($result));

$expected_result = (object)[
  "status"  => "Success",
  "data" => $result
];

echo(print_r($expected_result));
?>
```

JS version jsfiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/czdqqegq/`

```
var json =  [
  {
    "studentabsentId": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-11"
  },
  {
    "studentabsentId": [
      "1"
    ],
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12"
  },
  {
    "studentabsentId": [
      "2"
    ],
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-13"
  }
];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i<json.length; i++){
  for(var j =0; j<json[i].studentabsentId.length; j++){
    if(json[i].studentabsentId[j] === "2"){ /*Filter out where ID is 2*/
        result.push({
          "studentAbsentId" : json[i].studentabsentId[j],
          "studentAbsentDate" : json[i].studentAbsentDate      
        });
    }
  }
}
var expected_results = {
  "status" : "Success",
  "data" : result
}
console.log(expected_results);
```

Comment: Mr @Jaaaaaaay  i need answer in PHP,and jsfiddle link nothing is showing

Comment: Mr @Jaaaaaaay i am not able to do ,can you please update your answer in php

Comment: Mr @Jaaaaaaay, what happen please update your answer in php

Comment: Answer updated, you can check the result in the sandbox link

Comment: Mr @Jaaaaaaay please check my updated code , i am trying like that but i am getting error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What's your php version? And what exactly is the $optionsList, are you sure it is a string?

Comment: Very very thanks Mr @Jaaaaaaay, atlast i got the answer.